# How can I reduce size of generated PDF using iText7

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, itext7

I use this method to copy and scale page by page number from original PDF and put them to generated PDF which contains only selected and scaled pages from original PDF.

```
private static void addScaledPage(PdfDocument pdf, PdfDocument srcDoc, String pageNumber) throws IOException {
        PdfPage page = pdf.addNewPage(PageSize.A4);
        PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(page);
        AffineTransform transformationMatrix = AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(0.86, 0.86);
        canvas.concatMatrix(transformationMatrix);
        PdfFormXObject pageCopy = srcDoc.getPage(Integer.valueOf(pageNumber)).copyAsFormXObject(pdf);
        canvas.addXObject(pageCopy, 50, 30);
    }
```

This code works fine, but small issue happen when I try to take 3 pages from original PDF which have 140 pages and approx. 10 MB size => the generated PDF with 3 selected pages also have approx. 10 MB. 
Also, when I try to copy 3 pages or 10 pages from original document I got always the same size of generated PDF => it seems like references are copied from source PDF

I would appreciate to give me some advice, did I do something wrong in the implementation? Or some other advice?

Kindest regards,

Comment: Without having a look at the source pdf, I can't say for sure, but PDF does allow you to re-use objects, and copying a page as a formXObject will also copy all resources necessary to display that page. The observed behaviour could be explained if you're copying identical pages, and the original document re-uses the resources for this page. But 10MB is quite a lot for a single page :p

Comment: Any idea to solve this problem ... is it possible that getPage() or copyPagesTo() methods which are part of iText7 library take all resources from original source PDF document and copies it to the generated PDF?

Answer (score 0):

It depends a lot on the resources embedded in the document. If a large image that uses CMYK color, or a font with CJK glyphs (either of these resources could easily be several MB in size) is used on the pages you are copying, that entire resource will be copied into the PDF you're creating. The fact that you are only copying three out 140 pages wouldn't make much difference: the bulk of the file size will be taken up by the resource, and the pages won't display properly without it.

A solution would be a workflow that optimizes your document during or after copying the pages. This could convert images to an equivalent, smaller color space, or subset the font so that you only carry the required glyphs. Both of these techniques can substantially reduce the size of the file (but this is all dependent on how the source file itself is constructed, of course).